# Create different edit and create page in telerik mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

Im trying out Telerik and the application I am working on requires me to have a different create  and edit screen. In Mvc you of course had your create and edit page and you could edit those how you like. In Telerik you don't get those, but I was made aware you could create your own edit profile

I then proceeded to do that with the following code

```
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("editClient"))
```

Good news is that you get a different page for the edit, and the bad news is that, this is also now the create page. 
I'm grateful for assistance in getting this done.

Comment: What we do is create a template with conditional code depending on whether it is Add or Update. You can use the edit event to do things like change the button from Update to Add. `if (e.model.isNew) {...}` Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Yes i ended up doing that, but then, I have to write out controls for all my UI. Is there a way I can scaffold those two pageS?